# mySQL - inner join on basis of other inner join

Tags: mysql, select, join

So I have 3 tables:

1. "Sales" (with "barcode" column among others),
2. "Products" (with "barcode" and "image_id" columns among others) and
3. "Images" (with "image_id" and "image_data" columns among others).

My input data is a 12-digit number in "barcode" column of "Sales" table.

First, I need to find what image_id this barcode corresponds to (by using inner join with Products table):

```
SELECT image_id 
FROM tbl_products 
INNER JOIN tbl_sales 
ON tbl_products.barcode = tbl_sales.barcode
```

Now, I need to select "image_data" column from "Images" table by somehow inner joining the above selection result and "Images" table on image_id column.

How can I do this (if I can at all) in 1 query?

Comment: I don't understand. Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and explain what the problem is?  You seem to know enough SQL that `inner join images on images.image_id = tbl_sales.barcode` isn't sufficient.

Comment: the last one. don't know how to inner join on result of inner join.

Comment: Um select * From Some Table Inner Join SomeOtherTable on ... inner join YetAnother Table On ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT tbl_images.image_id, tbl_images.image_data 
FROM tbl_sales 
INNER JOIN tbl_products 
ON tbl_products.barcode = tbl_sales.barcode
inner join tbl_images
ON tbl_images.image_id = tbl_products.image_id
Where tbl_sales.BarCode = '0123456789AB'
```

Just chain your joins together. NB you can use aliases as well so

```
SELECT i.image_id, i.image_data 
FROM tbl_sales s 
INNER JOIN tbl_products p 
ON p.barcode = s.barcode
inner join tbl_images i
ON i.image_id = p.image_id
Where s.BarCode = '0123456789AB'
```

would work as well and be more readable.

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine (no need in SELECT string for the first field, I needed only the second one)!

Answer (score 0):

You can join multiple tables in one query. The syntax is the same when you join 2 tables. Also you can mix the join types:

**Example**

```
SELECT
    * -- Change it to the required field list!
FROM
    Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 T2
        ON T1.col1 = T2.col2
    INNER JOIN Table3 T3
        ON T2.col3 = T3.col4
    LEFT JOIN Table4 T4
        ON T1.col5 = T4.col6 AND T2.col7 = T3.col8
```

Some tips: Always use aliases for the joined tables and use those aliases when you use any columns anywhere in your query.